# 500 Internal Server Error on https://copyleaks.com/api/v3/education/submit/ocr/my-custom-id

Tags: copyleaks-api

I wanted to scan a free text only(images not included) from copyleaks and they offer me this documentation https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/education/submit/ocr but I'm getting the 500 Internal Server Error using this Request body(raw json type)

```
{
  "base64": "dGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveA==",
  "filename": "image.jpg",
  "langCode": "en",
  "properties": {
    "webhooks": {
      "status": "https://{yoursite.com}/webhook/{STATUS}/my-custom-id"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: {yoursite.com} was replaced with my actual url

I was able to get a 200 response from this request https://id.copyleaks.com/v3/account/login/api using this request body(raw json type)

```
{
    "email": "***",
    "key": "****"
}
```

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: You should ask Copyleaks instead.

Comment: Hi Jovet, two things: 1. your key was exposed to the public. Please renew it on Copyleaks dashboard. 2. If you got HTTP response code 500, you should also find a ticket number in it. What is the ticket id?